# How to calculate "top % all time"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page

I've been using the fact that my profile says "top 5% all time" as a bragging factor to demonstrate my knowledge to clients.

Now that I'm active again on the site it's started saying "top 2% this week" which isn't something I can put in a biography.

### The actual question

How can I calculate the statistics all-time top 5% myself?

I've tried googling and found:

> How to find what percent of X is Y: Use the percentage formula: Y/X = P%

So I tried:

```
my all-time ranking / number of users = %

19482 / 10652636 = 0.00182884311
```

Which is decimal form, so times 100 to get the percentage:

```
0.182884311
```

That's not 5%, so unless I've jumped a whole lot this month I've got this wrong.

Whatever it is, I'm clearly not getting into the top % of the Maths SE.

Comment: You could visit the user page and see where your name appears in "all time" https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all and then say you're in the top one hundred, one thousand  or whatever number that is.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's an option but not as impressive as being able to say "top 5% out of 10m developers". 5% sounds close to the top, #19482 sounds like I've got a lot of competition :)

Comment: But it's also more accurate, and easy to verify :) "all time" means when SO started in 2009 after all.

Comment: Thanks yeah I just wanted something to wow clients with, rather than to-the-decimal accurate. I think I answered my own question though.

Comment: *something to wow clients* .... How about: I survived on Stack Overflow ...

Comment: On a more serious note. The developer story has that percentage thingy for your tags.

Comment: Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1071744?UserId=156388) to give you those overall  stats.

Comment: @rene wow thats really cool thanks. I've bookmarked that :D

Answer (score 5):

I think I have answered my own question.

The sidebar says:

> - users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

This puts the total at 466849, not 10m.

Running the maths again shows:

```
19482 / 466849 = 4.17308380226
```

Which was probably rounded up to 5% last time I saw it.

So I guess that means I really am the top 0.18% of all users, and the top 4.17% of all serious answerers.

It's purely a vanity. I know that it's not really for all of time, and that there are plenty of skilled developers out there that aren't on SO, and even that you could rise in the ranks by just getting a few really popular answers.

The point is though that it's an impressive stat that will make me stand out to clients, and it's verifiable.

I have put a ton of time into answering forums over the years so you know what... I'm going to be proud of this :D

Comment: I think you mean that 19482/466849 = 0.0417308380226, or, put differently, numerator/demoninator x100%, is equivalent to 4.17308380226%.